# How to match a regex in Ballerina?

Tags: regex, ballerina, ballerina-swan-lake

I’m working on a Ballerina project and I’m trying to do a contains check as follows,

```
string key = "ownerEmail";
string url3 = "/guest-wifi-accounts/{ownerEmail}";
io:println(url3.matches(re `\{${key}\}`));
io:println(regex:matches(url3, string `\{${key}\}`));
io:println(regex:replaceAll(url3, string `\{${key}\}`, "abc@gmail.com"));
```

However, this gives me the following result

```
false
false
/guest-wifi-accounts/abc@gmail.com
```

Are there any alternative methods in Ballerina to perform regex matching?

Comment: `matches` requires a full string match. Use `find`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It is inappropriate to close a question about Ballerina as a duplicate of a Java question.

Comment: It is the same anyway. ``string:RegExp r = re `\{${key}\}`;``  and then `io:println(r.find(url3));` does what is required.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That it is conceptually the same does not make them a duplicate. These are two different languages with their own syntax and API.